# Difference between image in a web browser vs image in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, browser

I have a PNG image coming from a URL (internal to my company). When I navigate to that URL in my web browser, I see the image correctly (with transparency). I can see from Chrome's network tools that it's coming back as an image/png mime type as expected. I can save the image from the browser to my local hard drive and it ends up being about 32kb in size.

I wrote a simple Java program to pull the image down and save it programmatically. The save image code is very simple, shown below:

```
    public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
```

However, whenever I run this program the saved image is distorted. It ends up looking roughly the same except for a loss of transparency. Its size is only about 4kb. In addition to this, just looking at the bytes I can see the first 3 bytes are "GIF".

Would anyone be able to help me understand what's causing the difference?

(Note: The image URL I'm using in both cases actually points to a Java web application which is using ImageIO.read to return a BufferedImage from the real image URL.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public @ResponseBody BufferedImage getImage(@PathVariable String id) {
    try {
        //Modified slightly to protect the innocent
        return ImageIO.read((new URL(IMAGE_URL + id)).openStream());
    } catch (IOException io) {
        return defaultImage();
    }
}
```

and in my spring context file I have:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <!-- Converter for images -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="defaultContentType" value="image/png"/>
            </bean>
            <!-- This must come after our image converter -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Not sure if this extra layer makes a difference, but I thought it best to mention it.)

Any ideas/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
B.J.

Answer (score 1):

When you use ImageIO.read, you're getting a BufferedImage object, which is in Java's internal format, not in PNG format. If you write that out to a file, you're writing that internal representation. I'm a bit surprised it's readable at all.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't include the additional Spring code for clarification. I've edited my question to reflect the use of the Spring image converter.

Comment: @Benny Does chrome and the Java app trigger the same conversion code.  My guess would be that the Java app is not setting all the same headers as chrome, so the server returns different data.